# Angular router - routes to a weird route "?mat-radio-group-0=true"

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-routing, radio-group

I have this close button in my HTML template which fires a close() function in the component:
HTML template:

```
       <div>
          <label id="radio-group-label">Please specify: </label>
          <mat-radio-group
            fxLayout="row"
            aria-labelledby="radio-group-label"
            class="radio-group"
            formControlName="flWholeDay"
          >
            <mat-radio-button [checked]="wholeDayLeave" value="true"
              >Whole day</mat-radio-button
            >
            <mat-radio-button [checked]="!wholeDayLeave" value="false"
              >Part day</mat-radio-button
            >
          </mat-radio-group>
        </div>
```

HTML button:

```
<button mat-raised-button fxLayoutAlign="center center" color="accent" (click)="close()">Close</button>
```

Component:

```
 close() {
    this.router.navigate(['/something']);
  }
```

The problem is when the button is pressed it routes to http://localhost:4200/something?mat-radio-group-0=true 
Where is this odd thing happening?

Comment: Can you try after removing `/`?

Comment: try to use: `(click)=close($event)` and `close(event: Event) { event.preventDefault(); this.router.navigate(['/something']);}` Maybe your button is the only one inside a form .

Comment: using (click)=close($event) as per your suggestion also worked. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`button` elements have a `type` attribute that defaults to `"submit"`. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

Add `type="button"` to your button.

```
<button type="button" mat-raised-button fxLayoutAlign="center center" color="accent" (click)="close()">Close</button>
```